# Split Packages and Bootstrap Jars in Java 9

Tags: java, bootstrapping, java-9, java-module

It seems that in Java 9 it is not allowed to have so-called Split Packages, i.e. the same package being defined in two different modules. This causes a problem with my migration process: The (Gradle) project contains a Jar file that is called `bootstrap.jar`, with a structure like this:

```
bootstrap.jar
- com
  - example
    - Foo.class
    - Bar.class
    - Baz.class
```

The `src` directory contains a class `com.example.Bar` that depends on `Foo` as well as a module definition, for `com.example`. The `bootstrap.jar` file does not contain a module info, as it was compiled before Java 9, so it uses an automatic module called `bootstrap`. The problem is that now the package `com.example` is defined in both modules, `com.example` and `bootstrap`.

The reason there is this `bootstrap.jar` file, to begin with, is as follows:

The `src/com/example` folder actually contains `Bar.java`, `Baz.java` and another file, `Foo.dyvil`. The latter is written in a JVM-based programming language. So the dependency chain looks like this:

```
Bar.java -> Foo.dyvil -> Baz.java
```

During the build process, it gets compiled to `Foo.class`, which gets placed in a new Jar file that later replaces `bootstrap.jar`. The reason all these files are placed is that both the Java and Dyvil compiler cannot process the other languages files, so they require some access to the compiled classes from the previous build. So that is why there is `bootstrap.jar`.

Now for the actual problem: Since split packages are disallowed in Java 9, is there any way to achieve "split builds" using "bootstrap" jar files as described and used in my project? Or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 3):

Though the long-term solution to this is resolving such packages to exist in a single module and then modularising the code.

As a temporary solution, you can make use of the option:-

```
--patch-module <module>=<file>(<pathsep><file>)*
```

as in your case

```
--patch-module com.example=bootstrap.jar
```

Do keep in mind though, *the `--patch-module` option is intended only for testing and debugging. Its use in production settings is strongly discouraged.*

Comment: I guess that is ok since the `bootstrap.jar` is only used for build, after that everything the packages are no longer split

Comment: I assume I have to add these options as compiler arguments in gradle, but how do I make use of this in IntelliJ?

Comment: True for gradle and VM options in Edit run configurations is where you can use them in intelliJ.

Comment: But how do I set it up so IntelliJ build also uses this option?

Comment: @Clashsoft I hope I answered that in the previous comment as well. To build it via intelliJ you can edit and configure the run.